# Icons changed after removal of playonlinux and wine, how to fix?

Tags: package-management, wine, ubuntu-gnome, playonlinux, system-settings

After removing playonlinux and wine the icon of files and softwares are changed. see some screen-shot below.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try rebooting the machine and tell us if its still the case.

Comment: And also try changing the icon theme using (GNOME) Tweaks.

Comment: after changing icons in gnome tweaks the problem is solved.....thank you...